Should we add "category-theory" tag?
There is emerging field of categorical deep learning whose recent article is https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.15332 and their company has just raised 33M from Khosla ventures https://techcrunch.com/2024/04/09/symbolica-hopes-to-head-off-the-ai-arms-race-by-betting-on-symbolic-models
And I have just asked question about their article:
Trying to understand Ch.2.1 "2.1. Monads and their algebras" of "Categorical Deep Learning: An Algebraic Theory of Architectures"
Unfortunately, there are not tags 'category-theory' or 'categorical-deep-learning' in Data Science Stackexchange. Maybe we should create one and apply it to my question?

You can create tags directly from the Ask Question page, after you've gotten that privilege at 150 rep.  If there were a serious need and you hadn't the reputation, I would create it for you based on this meta question.
For now though, I think we can hold off.  If and when more questions arrive that could use that tag, we can add it.  (They might help guide whether the tag should be 'category-theory' or 'categorical-deep-learning' or something else.)
